# dl.google.com connection refused and Unknown Host messages

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have just installed Android Studio and put together my first skeleton app. I'm not entirely sure what I need to do to set up an emulator with which to test it but from reading around I worked out that I needed to install some system images (whatever they are).

I therefore went into the Android SDK manager and, under packages, I expanded Android 4.3.1 (API18), which was closest to the target I had chosen for my app. None of the items in this section were installed so I ticked them all and clicked on Install 18 packages. It started off OK and the first item (SDK Platform) seems to have installed OK but nothing else. I tried again. The second time, the SDK manager log starts like this:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 22, revision 1
Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl.google.com refused
Downloading SDK Platform Android 5.1, API 22, revision 1
Installing SDK Platform Android 5.1, API 22, revision 1
Installed SDK Platform Android 5.1, API 22, revision 1
Downloading Samples for SDK API 22, revision 5
Download interrupted: Read timed out
Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 2
Download interrupted: Unknown Host dl.google.com
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 22, revision 1
Download interrupted: Unknown Host dl.google.com
Downloading Android Support Library, revision 22
Download interrupted: Unknown Host dl.google.com
```

Any suggestions why I am getting these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I fall in the same problem, in my case, instead of going directly to android sdk manager, I opened Android Studio (version 1.5.1) [studio64.exe, run as admin] searched for 'sdk manager' in search box, then clicked on the result to open it's sdk manager, from there everything was fine to be downloaded and installed.